# Is it possible to 'clip' two line layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, line

Specifically, I am looking to merge my bus route network into my wider road network. I only want to work with roads which lie on the bus network. Is this type of clipping possible? Joining the attributes of the layers is proving problematic.

Comment: You have a line. You have a second line crossing the first one. You clip them. Now you have a line with a cut. What did you gain?
Can you expand on "joining is problematic"?

Comment: In QGIS you can only clip lines-polygons, not lines-lines (unless there is a plug-in or an obscure code I am missing), so unfortunately, it doesn't appear that simple. Joining is problematic because I can't seperate the roads not on the bus network. The joined layer ends up being the whole road network

Comment: I wanted to point out that you can't clip stuff by lines, since it geometrically doesn't work nor make sense. I think you are doing something wrong or missing a step when it comes to joining. May I suggest opening a new question describing your workflow and including screenshots?

Comment: The *term of art* for your task is [conflation](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Conflation)

Answer (score 4):

If your lines are perfectly coincident, an intersect will work. Otherwise, I suggest that you make a small buffer around your lines, then you can clip the lines where you need based on the polygons.